# Openlayers 3 FreeDraw like Leaflet.FreeDraw

Tags: leaflet, openlayers-3

Somebody knows if OpenLayers 3 had the plugin for free draw on the map like Leaflet.Freedraw ?

[Leaflet.FreeDraw](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw)

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no need for a plugin. It's already integrated in the library itself with drawing component [`ol.interaction.Draw`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html). You will see it has a `freehandCondition` option.

By default, you just need to go to [the official Draw Features demo](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-features.html), choose to draw a "LineString" or a "Polygon" by maintaining Shift button while drawing and it should work.

Comment: It has a problem, i look for this example for freehand draw : 
https://jsfiddle.net/tdf08y9x/ 
It's work, ok, and i change this line 
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ dragPan: true }). So the draw is don't display when after drawing.